# create cell table with two list box and one editable text field in gwt

Tags: gwt, inline-editing, gwt-celltable

1)I have one button.On clicking on that button will create a row in celltable.In which first two columns are list boxes.Lists will have some predefined values coming from DB.Third column will have one text field.
User will enter some value in that text field and user will select some values from above mentioned list and save that row data.

2)Loading that page again will display one row created by user previously.
Now user can again edit and save that row again or can create new row by clicking on that button.

How can i implement above mentioned functionality by using gwt celltable?
anyone please help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Asking a clear question will make it easier to help you. Including the work that you've done until now and sharing  the error if there is any is very important. please read this article to make sure that you get a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic manipulation with the CellTable is illustrated in the Showcase of features. There is an [example for the CellTable](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable), the source code of which you can see if you click "Source code" link-button in the top of the page (near "Example" button).

**Note** that there is several source code files (GUI+Java source) can be chosen with the drop-down list.

Comment: Thanks..it will definitely help me..:)